# .NET 3.5 Hosting in IE11/Windows 8.1

Tags: .net, winforms, wcf, internet-explorer, windowsformshost

I have an application where I host a .NET 3.5 Windows Forms control in Internet explorer to provide access to a printer. The control works fine in IE7 through IE10 (desktop), but it will not work in IE11 on Windows 8.1 (again in desktop mode).

The PC in question has both .NET 2.0/3.0/3.5 and .NET 4.0/4.5 installed and enabled, the site has been added to the trusted zone, CASPOL permissions have been set the same as they are on the PC's running IE7 through 10 and EnableIEHosting has been set to 1 at both 32 and 64bit levels on the PC.

I have also tried DebugIEHost. The log from which indicates that the forms control is in fact being created. Debugging locally indicates that the problem lies in calling a method of the control (from JavaScript) which never seems to return and never seems to actually run either. All I am left with is a locked IE11 that has to be closed from task manager.

*As previously stated, this has worked without problem from IE7 through IE10 on Windows XP through Windows 8.0 and I am absolutely certain that the CASPOL configurations etc. have been set correctly.*

Is anybody aware of any other problems or new configuration requirements when hosting .NET Windows Forms controls in IE11?

**UPDATE #1**

I have now been able to tie this down further. I have diagnosed that it is actually the constructor of a WCF service client that fails to return. It is a simple generated client class and as such simply calls the base constructor with the endpoint configuration name; unfortunately, it is failing within the call to the base class `ClientBase<T>.ClientBase(string endpointConfigurationName)`.

Given this new information, I have tried disabling the Windows Firewall in case this was in some way blocking the service client from being created (though realistically I would not expect the firewall to intervene with anything until such time as a request was actually made by the client). No difference.

I have also tried calling the default (parameterless) constructor; again no difference.

My only other thought is the configuration of the service client. This is as follows in case there is something that stands out to anybody...

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false" />
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/MyWeb/Services/MyService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMyService" contract="wcfWS.IMyService" name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This configuration is as generated by the WCF Service reference of VS2012.

Just for reference, the control calls a WCF service to retrieve more detailed information about an object whose reference/id has been passed in via the JavaScript call; i.e. I pass in ID=1, and the control then calls the WCF service with ID=1 to retrieve the details before sending those details to the printer. It is the call to the constructor of the client for this WCF service that is hanging.

Comment: "It used to work before" doesn't help us help you.  A debugger's stack trace would help.  Enable unmanaged code debugging and the Microsoft Symbol server.

Comment: @Hans: thanks, but I have been unable to debug the control directly whilst it is hosted in IE. I have however been adding additional output to enable me to trace how far it is getting and have subsequently updated the post with this information. I do realise that my original request did not provide a great deal of information, but that was all that was available at the time and - at the time - I was concerned this might be a known issue where perhaps functionality had been removed from IE11 and the removal of that functionality was actually the cause of my problems.

Answer (score 1):

I got breakthrough.

As we cannot deploy service config in web application that hosts windows form control.
I created constructor in code itself and it worked absolutely fine.

Following is code sample.

```
    Dim binding As New BasicHttpBinding
    Dim endPoint As New EndpointAddress("http://SERVERNAME/<WEBSITE>/YOURSERVICE.svc")
    Dim obj As New TestWCFService.TestWCFServiceClient(binding, endPoint)
```

Hope this works for you too.